# Don't want to display count values ( which is equal to 0 ) in the html table when sending mail.

Tags: java, html, jakarta-mail

In my code (which is in Java) I am calculating the occurrence of certain strings in the mail subject and I am supposed to send a mail displaying that info in a table format. The table contains two fields the "string names" and the "count value" for that string. I am able to do that but I don't want to display the count value of the string where the count value of the string is equal to zero. The count variables just increments by one (count++) when that string is occurred.

I was thinking to opt for the Object convention for those count variables where I can display it both as number and an empty string when required in table (html format) but performing that increment is not possible on Object variables.

Is there any way I can overcome this problem?

## Below is the code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException{
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com", senderid = "<sender_id>@gmail.com", recipient = "<recipient_id>@gmail.com";
    String password = "*******";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    // Get the Session object.
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
       protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
          return new PasswordAuthentication(senderid, password);
       }
    });

    System.out.println("Sending mail");

    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(senderid));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
    InternetAddress.parse(recipient));
    message.setSubject("Test");

    message.setContent(<table_format stored a string which accesses the count variable in its <td> tag>, "text/html");
    Transport.send(message);

    System.out.println("Done");

}
```

This is a working code snippet. The count value is coming from a different class. I just want to skip displaying the count value which is 0 in the table.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like the place to remove the zero counts is in the code that returns them instead of parsing a result string here. Can you share that code?

Comment: @Mureinik added the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Table {

/* The count values are coming from static variables from the other class (Mail) where the increment is happening by checking the mail subject */
/* Below is where I am accesing the variables in the function*/  

  public static String report_table = 
       "<table border='1' width='800' style='border-collapse:collapse;text-align:center'>"
       + "<tr>"
       + "<th style='padding:5px ; background-color:#78909c'>String</th>"
       + "<th style='padding:5px; background-color: #78909c'>Count Value</th>"
       + "</tr>"

       + "<tr>"
       + "<td style='background-color:#78909c;'>Filesize</td>"
       + "<td>"+Mail.filesize_count+"</td>"
       + "</tr>"

       + "<tr>"
       + "<td style='background-color:#78909c;'>Memory</td>"
       + "<td>"+Mail.memory_count+"</td>"
       + "</tr>"
       + "<tr>"
       + "<td style='background-color:#78909c;'>Content</td>"
       + "<td>"+Mail.content_count+"</td>"
       + "</tr>"
       + "</table>"

       +"<br><br>"
       +"<b>"
       +"Regards"+","+"<br>"
       +"Nikhil"
       +"</b>" ;
}
```

This is the class where the count values are stored in a table.

Comment: Construct the String in a StringBuilder and conditionally add the snippets with the counts.

Comment: Hi @BillShannon that really helped alot. It was a little tedious job manually checking the condition and appending but it is working now. Thanks alot for pointing this out.